# "URL Segment Support" configs on Apache mod-PHP 7.2 server

Tags: url, segments, server-migration

I'm moving a site from Nexcess to Google Cloud hosting, and it appears the server doesn't support URL segments by default.

What do I need to have my web hosting do in order to enable this? They said they need the info from EE on what to do to configure this, but it's not anywhere in the docs (that I can find)?

The requirements are here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/installation/requirements.html and the URL Segments section is at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server just needs to pass environmental variables on to PHP. For segment support, this means that PHP needs the ability to access the portion of the URI after the script name, e.g. the `foo/bar` bit of `index.php/foo/bar`. Typically this is passed to PHP by Apache as `PATH_INFO` or `ORIG_PATH_INFO`.

Try creating new file on the server named `pathtest.php` with the following:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SERVER);
echo '</pre>';
```

And access it at `https://example.com/pathtest.php/foo/bar`. You should see an environment variable available such as one of the two mentioned that has the value of `/foo/bar`.